# Saving an entire Webpage to a single database field

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, ckeditor

I'm using inline CKEditor in my symfony2 project, when the user logs into the site administrator account, the user is presented with inline editors to alter the page content, after changing the content and saving the changes, the entire page is persisted to a field in the database.

As there are too many individual component to have individual rows for each of them i'm thinking of saving the entire page as one piece.the web page might have around 36000 charcters,

What field type would be best?

Is there a better approach to this?

And how is inline editing generally saved to the server?

-thanks

Comment: Why a mysql database and not a file in the file-server? Does it *have* to go into mysql?

Comment: No not necessariy, would't a database be easier to maintain with update and delete operations? if there are some advantages that a file based approach could offer i would't mind using it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't just go saving webpages in the database.

Depending on the amount of your content, you might need to change the column's data type.

I presume, that currently you're using **TEXT**, you can try **MEDIUMTEXT** which can store up to 16MB of data or **LONGTEXT** for up to 4GB of data.

But you should never store static HTML that repeats over and over in the database. Basic caching will help.

Comment: It all depends what kind of data are you actually saving in there. Are these just content from the editor?

Comment: its an entire html page, starting from <html> to </html> and everyting in between! would writing to a page be better?

Comment: So, you let the users enter all of the HTML data? That does seem fairly insecure, considering they can add malicious javascript.

Answer (score 4):

### The (simplified) usual practice:

There are some repetitive chunks of HTML such as the header, menus, sidebar, footer etc.. None of these chunks are ever saved in the database. They get included from template files.

The page specific chunks of HTML (the page content) are saved in the database.

For example you could create the following basic structure: one table named `pages` which contains the following columns `id, url, title, content` and another table storing named `menus` which could contain the following columns `id, title, page_id`.

When you display a page you first fetch a record from `pages` from the DB and then use a template to render that information.

The template will include other templates for the header, menus, sidebar, content, footer.

The menus template will receive a list of all of the menu items (and links to them). The content template will render the HTML from `pages.content`. All other templates are fixed HTML nothing dynamic in them.